# How do I delete Excel files column on Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to delete many Excel files in folder at once.
So I write below code, but when it runs, terminal logged out `Delete Method of Range class failed` error popping up. 
and more confusing thing, in some worksheet's delete process runs successfully.
I think, it causes from can not do release sheet object of powershell well.

can anybody help me? regards.

```
# Launch Excel
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} 
$baseDir = Convert-Path $(Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName -Parent)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { $_.Extension -eq ".xlsx" }  

# "${baseDir}\{$_.name}"
# Open Book
$files| 
%{
    Write-Host $_.Name
    $excel.Workbooks.Open("${baseDir}\" + $_.name) | %{
        $_.Worksheets | %{
            # Delete Column
            # $_.Activate
            Write-Host $_.Name

            #$_.Columns.Item("J").Delete()
            #$_.Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.Delete()
            #$_.Columns.item(3).Insert()
            #$_.Range("J:J").Delete()
            $_.Columns("J").Delete()
        }
        $_.Save()
    }
}

# Excel 
$excel.Quit()
\[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Maybe look into this module https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel . It's considered to be more user-friendly than using the com object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to delete the J Column in every sheet of every workbook, this might help

```
$files| % {
    # Prints name of File
    Write-Host $_.Name

    # There is always one workbook. 
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName) # FullName has the complete path.
    $workbook.Worksheets | % {
        # prints name of each worksheet
        Write-Host $_.Name

        # Deletes the column
        $_.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Delete() # prints True if successful.

        # Or you can use the above statement in an IF statement.
        if ($_.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Delete()) {
           Write-Host "Column J Deleted successfully"
        } 
        # else print it didnt for $_.Name worksheet.
    }
    $workbook.Save()
}
```